# omniauth-facebook user profile becomes the admins' picture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I integrated the omniauth-facebook gem with gem into my website and added some Facebook friends as testers for my app but every time someone signs in using Facebook my picture as an admin gets persisted as their picture. The strange thing is that their first name and last name gets persisted correctly. The app is still in sandbox mode.

in models/user.rb I've got

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.firstname = auth.info.first_name
    user.lastname = auth.info.last_name
    user.avatar = auth.info.image
  end
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
  super.tap do |user|
    if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
      user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

and in initializers/devise.rb I've got

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP-ID", "APP-SECRET", :scope => "email, public_profile", :image_size => "normal", :secure_image_url => true
```

**Edit 1:**
I'm hosting the pictures using a dropbox app. In the app I can see the testers pictures get persisted as picture, picture (1), picture (2) and so on. When I open the rails console the avatar_file_name (since I use the paperclip gem) is "picture" for every testers profile, hence all get the same profile picture. Is there a method to save the picture as picture-"UID" so they all get a different name?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the solution to the problem can be solved by using the path option.

in models/user.rb and added the fingerprint to make even more of a disinction.

```
fingerprint = Time.now

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :pin => "30x30>" }, :default_url => "/images/missing.png", :storage => :dropbox, :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"), :path => ":style/#{fingerprint}_:id_:filename"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```